# A way to find a specific single character - grok pattern

Tags: grok

So as the tittle says, currently starting messing around with Grok patterns for a work project but I'm having some issues with it. Basically I process the log initially then check if on the message (field) itself it exists a "%" symbol, because if it does I want to "re-grok" the message, I will paste the code as I believe it will help illustrate the issue:

```
filter {
   if [solution] == "horizon" {
      grok {
         id => "horizon_base_grok"
         match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{LOGLEVEL:log-level}  %{DATA:horizon.component}             %{DATA:horizon.process}:%{GREEDYDATA:message}" }
         overwrite => ["message"]
         if '%' in [message] {
            match => { "message" => "%{DATA:free_mem_string} < %{NUMBER:free_mem_value:int}%{GREEDYDATA:message}" }
            overwrite => ["message"]
         }
      }
      if [log-level] not in [ "ERROR","WARN","FATAL" ] {
         drop {}
      }
   }

   date {
      id => "horizon_date"
      match => [ "timestamp","ISO8601" ]
      add_tag => [ "horizon_date" ]
   }
}
```

If I remove this part:

```
if '%' in [message] {
            match => { "message" => "%{DATA:free_mem_string} < %{NUMBER:free_mem_value:int}%{GREEDYDATA:message}" }
            overwrite => ["message"]
         }
```

Everything works properly, but with that piece of code we stop getting logs on Kibana. I have tested to input the Grok pattern on an online debugger and it works, so I'm almost 100% sure the issue is on the "if" statement.

Could you please assist ? Much appreciated!

Comment: I have mostly seen `"%" in [message]`, i.e. string containment (with double quotes), not single character containment (with single quotes). Not saying that it is wrong, just that I would try with double quotes, to be sure.

Comment: Hey @cornuz thanks for the feedback, yes tried that first actually, I've tried almost every variation i could think of on the "if" statement